# Adding ipv6 address to firewall rule in windows programmatically

Tags: vb.net

I am struggling to add ipv6 addresses to firewall rule, ipv4 I was able to add with . could anyone help me out with it would be great

```
Imports NetFwTypeLib
Imports System.Net


Public Class Firewall
    Implements IDisposable
    Private _policy As INetFwPolicy2 = Nothing

    Private ReadOnly Property Policy As INetFwPolicy2
        Get
            If _policy Is Nothing Then
                _policy = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2")), INetFwPolicy2)
            End If
            Return _policy
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub Add(ipAddress As String, ruleName As String)

        Dim firewallRule As NetFwTypeLib.INetFwRule = Policy.Rules.Item(ruleName)
        'Dim NewAddress As String = ipAddress.ToString & "/255.255.255.255"
        Dim NewAddress As String = ipAddress.ToString
        If Not firewallRule.RemoteAddresses.Contains(NewAddress) Then
            firewallRule.RemoteAddresses += "," & NewAddress
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1775237-ipv6-windows-firewall-rule

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else faced the same found the answer

```
Imports System.Net


Public Class Firewall
    Implements IDisposable
    Private _policy As INetFwPolicy2 = Nothing

    Private ReadOnly Property Policy As INetFwPolicy2
        Get
            If _policy Is Nothing Then
                _policy = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2")), INetFwPolicy2)
            End If
            Return _policy
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub Add(ipAddress As String, ruleName As String)
        Dim firewallRule As NetFwTypeLib.INetFwRule = Policy.Rules.Item(ruleName)
        Dim NewAddress As String
        If IpClass(ipAddress).Equals("ipv4") Then
            NewAddress = ipAddress.ToString & "/255.255.255.255"
        Else
            NewAddress = ipAddress.ToString & "/128"
        End If
        If Not firewallRule.RemoteAddresses.Contains(NewAddress) Then
            firewallRule.RemoteAddresses += "," & NewAddress
        End If
    End Sub




    Public Sub Remove(ipAddress As String, ruleName As String)
        Dim firewallRule As NetFwTypeLib.INetFwRule = Policy.Rules.Item(ruleName)
        Dim NewAddress As String
        If IpClass(ipAddress).Equals("ipv4") Then
            NewAddress = ipAddress.ToString & "/255.255.255.255"
        Else
            NewAddress = ipAddress.ToString & "/128"
        End If

        If firewallRule.RemoteAddresses.Contains(NewAddress) Then
            Dim ipList As String = firewallRule.RemoteAddresses
            ipList = ipList.Replace(NewAddress, "")
            ipList = ipList.Replace(",,", ",")
            firewallRule.RemoteAddresses = ipList
        End If
    End Sub  


    Public Function Exists(ipAddress As String, ruleName As String) As Boolean
        Dim firewallRule As NetFwTypeLib.INetFwRule = Policy.Rules.Item(ruleName)
        Dim NewAddress4 As String = ipAddress.ToString & "/255.255.255.255"
        Dim NewAddress6 As String = ipAddress.ToString & "/128"
        If firewallRule.RemoteAddresses.Contains(NewAddress4) Or firewallRule.RemoteAddresses.Contains(NewAddress6) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function IsAddressValid(ByVal addrString As String) As Boolean
        Dim address As IPAddress = Nothing
        Return IPAddress.TryParse(addrString, address)
    End Function


    Public Function IpClass(ipAddress As String) As String
        If ipAddress.Contains(".") Then
            Return "ipv4"
        Else
            Return "ipv6"
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).